# SVN does not import .so files

Tags: android, svn

I am importing Android source code base into SVN. Android provides lots of .so and .a files in its release. These .so and .a file are not getting imported into svn.

The following are the related items in my "config" file, still it not importing.

- The gloabl ignore flag. It is commented by default
  '#' global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
  '#'   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
- The auto properties. It has been set to yes
  enable-auto-props = yes
- .so file enabled in auto properties flag.
  [auto-props]
  *.c = svn:eol-style=native
  *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
  *.h = svn:eol-style=native
  '#' *.dsp = svn:eol-style=CRLF
  '#' *.dsw = svn:eol-style=CRLF
  '#' *.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
  *.txt = svn:eol-style=native
  *.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
  *.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg
  Makefile = svn:eol-style=native
  *.so = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream
  *.a = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream

  .so.* = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream

Inspite of all this I am unable to import the .so and .a files.  Need suggestions.

Thanks,
ARVR

Comment: Forgot, to specify, if I do 'svn add *', without any --no-ignore, the .so and .a files do get added without any issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you have not set a global ignore at all, then SVN automatically uses the default global ignore.
That means, the line

> # global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so .so.[0-9] *.a *.pyc *.pyo '#' *.rej ~ ## .#* .*.swp .DS_Store

is actually the very same as:

> global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so .so.[0-9] *.a *.pyc
>   *.pyo '#' *.rej ~ ## .#* .*.swp .DS_Store

since if nothing is specified, the default value is used.

To **not** ignore *.so and .so.[0-9] files, you have to uncomment the gobal-ignores part in your config file and either specify there an empty line or your own global ignore list.

Comment: oh yes, Thanks This DID work. I never realized that "not" ignoring is equal to ignoring. Somewhere the documentation or the svn book could have specified it.  I did update my config file to uncomment the global-ignores and removed of *.so *.a so.[0-9] from the line, left the rest as it it.  Post this svn import did import all the file.  Thanks for the solution

Comment: That's seriously non-intuitive on the part of the subversion team.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an active `svn:ignore` rule which blocks the import.